# How to know if lists inside list contain the same elements

Tags: python

Is there a way to know if the lists inside a list contain the same elements with python?

**For example:**

Return True if given list `[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B']]` or False if given list `[['B', 'C'], ['Z', 'C']]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` which only contains unique value

```
l = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B']]
def find_uniqueness(l):
  l = set(tuple(row) for row in l)
  if len(set(l)) <= 1:
    print("Same data")
    return True
  else:
    print("Multiple unique data")
    return False

find_uniqueness(l)
```

Comment: `len(set(l)) >1` or `len(set(l)) ==1`

Comment: @lucumt What if the list is empty?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
same_elements_exist = len({tuple(e) for e in lst}) <= 1
```

Note that it considers the order of the elements while comparing.

If you don't need to consider order then do `sorted`

```
same_elements_exist = len({tuple(sorted(e)) for e in lst}) <= 1
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but for [[A,B],[A,B],[A,C]] this will return true when they are not the same elements.

Comment: How does this answer get 3 upvotes without even producing the right output?

Comment: @blhsing I misunderstood the question. I edited the answer to see if len is 1 which will return true if all elements in the list are same, and not just it contains any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the sub-lists to tuples and then putting them in a set, as answers from @PrakashDahal and @SomeDude are, may make the code appear to be concise and clever, but is inefficient if either the sub-lists or the main list is long since the tuple conversion and set creation do no benefit from any short-circuiting when there are any items that are different.

Instead, get the first sub-list from the list and then iterate through the rest of the list to validate that all of the sub-lists are equal to the first sub-list. If at any point any sub-list is found to be different, the iteration would end and not waste time validating the rest of the list. Any sub-list can be found different if any item is different from the corresponding item in the first sub-list when iterating through each sub-list, so it benefits from short-circuiting there as well:

```
def is_same(lst):
    if not lst:
        return True
    seq = iter(lst)
    first = next(seq)
    return all(i == first for i in seq)
```